# Windows Server GUI to Server Core EventID to determine time/who changed configuration

Tags: windows, graphical-user-interface

I need to find when/who converted a server from a GUI install to a Core install. 
I believe there is likely to be an EventID that corresponds to the time of the change.
I've searched for the EventID that might correspond to the change from Gui > Core and Core > Gui but I'm coming up dry.
Do you know what EVENTID I should look for? Or how to find it on Google/Serverfault/Microsoft?